# Ul , Ol not showing numbers and circle

Tags: html, css

Hi I seem to be having some problems regarding the ol and ul tags not showing the numbers and circle on the left syde.I am not using reset css.Here is my code:

```
             <ol>
                <li>ALL FILES</li>
                <li>PHP SCRIPTS</li>
                <li>WORDPRESS</li>
                <li>JAVASCRIPT</li>
                <li>CSS MOBILE</li>
            </ol>
            <ul>
                <li>ALL FILES</li>
                <li>PHP SCRIPTS</li>
                <li>WORDPRESS</li>
                <li>JAVASCRIPT</li>
                <li>CSS MOBILE</li>
           </ul>
           <ul>
                <li>ALL FILES</li>
                <li>PHP SCRIPTS</li>
                <li>WORDPRESS</li>
                <li>JAVASCRIPT</li>
                <li>CSS MOBILE</li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
               <li>ALL FILES</li>
               <li>PHP SCRIPTS</li>
               <li>WORDPRESS</li>
               <li>JAVASCRIPT</li>
               <li>CSS MOBILE</li>
          </ul>


#menu .dropdown_3columns li {
    float: none;
    position: static;
    text-align: left;
}
#menu li {
    border: medium none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 28px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

How can I make the ol an ul show the numbers and circles?

**EDIT:** Hover over List to see what I mean:

[link](http://www.key4dd.netne.net/)

Comment: For ol, use attribute Type=1 and for UL, Type="Circle" ?

Comment: The code you provided works just fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/zbKtr/

Comment: give me a minute I am uploading the site to the server so I can show you what I mean

Comment: Did you mind like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/c43zf/

Comment: Take a look at all your CSS files and check if there is a site-wide style set for the ul and ol tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other answers mentioned, the problem is caused by the li elements being set to `display: block` - this makes them take up the entire width set for them and forces the numbers or bullets out of the visible area.

To fix this, change the CSS from

```
#menu li {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 18px;
}
```

to this:

```
#menu li {
    display: inline-block; /* prevents the bullets being forced off the left-hand side, but still allows padding to be applied */
    padding-left: 8px;
    margin-left: 10px; /* This gives enough room for the bullets to be shown */
}
```

You've also set all `li` elements to be decimal in this section:

```
#menu .dropdown_3columns ol,
#menu .dropdown_3columns ul {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

so if you want bullet points instead of numbers, add the following after this section:

```
#menu .dropdown_3columns ul {
    list-style-type: disc; /* or circle etc */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

remove display:block; in #menu li and remove list-style-type: decimal;

```
#menu li {
display: block; //remove this line
}
```

and remove

```
#menu .dropdown_3columns ol, #menu .dropdown_3columns ul{
list-style-type: decimal; //remove this line
}
```

Comment: I have provided a link with the site and for some reason it does not work

Comment: remove display:block; in #menu li and remove  list-style-type: decimal;

Answer (score 2):

.....................................................

Hi now **remove** to the `#menu li display:block;`

as like this

```
#menu li{
display:block; // remove this line
}
```